# Do Gamecubes (DOL-001) without Digital AV exist?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

I just bought a Gamecube (DOL-001) and it doesn't have the Digital AV out.

Is that common? Because I read all over the internet that all DOL-001 models had digital AV.
Have I just discovered a new revision?

Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: Where did you buy it?

Comment: In Argentina, most here are US imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GameCube DOL-101 only had analog AV out

GameCube DOL-001 has both analog AV out and digital AV out

Which makes me believe your GameCube has been altered or repaired in some way with improper parts, it could be as simple as the back plate with the sticker being replaced because it was cracked

Source: